# Is code execution time limited by the block time?

Tags: mining, evm, block-interval, whisper

I'm fairly new to Ethereum, and I'm still trying to grasp the potential uses. I keep seeing articles using encrypted instant messaging as a potential application. But, there is a problem with this: from what I understand, a contract will be executed by all of the nodes on the network. The time it takes to mine a new block is ~20 seconds. So doesn't this mean that a message can take up to 20 seconds between the time it's send and received? If this is true, I can see this being a problem for real-time web applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, yes, code execution time is limited by the block time.

But on a practical level, **gas costs and the block gas limit are what limit code execution time**.  Try writing a contract that takes many milliseconds and you will probably find that you have exceeded the block gas limit.

FYI the average block time is 15 seconds.  [Whisper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/127/what-is-whisper-and-what-is-it-used-for) is the messaging part of the Ethereum technology suite.

Answer (score 0):

> So doesn't this mean that a message can take up to 20 seconds between
>   the time it's send and received?

It's worse! There is a variance between 3 s to more than 75s. [I try to find out the shape of the distribution of the block time](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5879/what-is-the-measured-distribution-of-block-times-since-homestead).