# What is the measured distribution of block times since Homestead?

Tags: homestead, block-interval

The variance of *block times* should arguably follow a Poisson distribution. But by casual observation I've seen blocks fast as 4 s or 1 m 15 s. The average is around 14 s since Homestead.
[If it follows a Poisson distribution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Poisson+distribution,+mean+%3D+2.9) it would have not that huge variance I observe:

[image]

*What is the true distribution of block times in Homestead, derived from empirical observation?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all it seems that I am *too ignorant* to understand Poissons Lamda!
At least I have some R skills left:

```
Summary:
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    5.00   10.00   14.35   19.00  155.00
```

Interpretation: if you take the mean and forget the stupid outliers we *count with only 10 s block time!*

[image: density block time]
[image: cdf block time]

The good news: *99% blocks are under 1 min*

```
 quantile(blocktimes$blocktime, c(.9,.95,.99))
 90% 95% 99% 
 31  40  61
```

**The peak is around 2.9 s**

[image]

[Source code on Github](https://github.com/rolandkofler/blocktime)

Comment: In your raw data, did you find any blocktimes where the blocktime is earlier than the parent blocktime? See [Can a child block have an earlier timestamp than the parent block?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/can-a-child-block-have-an-earlier-timestamp-than-the-parent-block).

Comment: Answered your question there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please see these statistics from etherchain.org: https://stats.etherchain.org/dashboard/db/average-block-time?theme=light :)

Comment: Sorry but it shows only the daily average block time. I'm looking for the statistical distribution of block times. A man with one hand in the freezer and one in the oven can enjoy room temperature on average ;-)

Comment: added more details