# what is block.timestamp

Tags: evm, opcode

In a function, does block.timestamp record the time the transaction was processed, or the time the block.timestamp computational step was processed?

Is block.timestamp the time the transaction is processed, or would `time` and `time2` differ ?

```
function doSomething() {

uint time = block.timestamp

// ... a few 400000 gas of other things ... //

uint time2 = block.timestamp

}
```

Answer (score 14):

As per the [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=timestamp#opcodes.) you will find

> timestamp of the current block in seconds since the epoch

so you have a single timestamp (when it is created) per block therefore time1=time2

read more about timestamp at [Is the block.timestamp value in Solidity seconds or milliseconds?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/is-the-block-timestamp-value-in-solidity-seconds-or-milliseconds)

Answer (score 7):

In reference to your comment about transaction timestamps, the timestamps of all transactions in a block are the same.

There can be many transactions in a block, all have the same timestamp, and all are the same timestamp as the block's.

Answer (score 5):

block.timestamp is the value what miner decides to publish there when he or she finds a block.

It is subject to some interpretation and can be skewed, though only for a while. In practice this is not a real problem and risks of using block number are often higher.

[How would a miner cope with a huge block time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/how-would-a-miner-cope-with-a-huge-block-time/5933#5933)

[How does Ethereum avoid inaccurate timestamps in blocks?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9564/how-does-ethereum-avoid-inaccurate-timestamps-in-blocks)

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/428/620