# Avoid using block.timestamp

Tags: contract-development, blocks, timestamp

I need to define a specific time phase. Therefore, I wanted to use opening timestamp and closing timestamp using `block.timestamp`. I get the following warning:

```
Linter: security/no-block-members: Avoid using 'block.timestamp'.
```

with the explanation that `block.timestamp` can be manipulated by miners.

Is there another solution working with timestamp or defining a time phase resp.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This linter advice is incorrect and in practice `block.timestamp` is safe. The risks of using block numbers are higher because the block production rate is not deterministic. The linter advice is based on non-realistic security assumptions that are not a concern under any kind of real scenario.

[More information on this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11072/620).